# How to create custom pdf annotation using PDPageContentStream class of pdfbox library?

Tags: pdf, annotations, pdfbox

I have implemented functionality to create cloud markups using the addBezier curve methods of the PDPageContentStream class. Now, I want create this markups as page annotation, so that I can delete these markups. I tried creating custom annotation using the PDAnnotation.createAnnotation method but it requires COSBase variable. So, how do I create a COSBase variable using the PDPageContentStream class to specify the shape of annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something alone the lines of

```
    PDAnnotation annot = new PDAnnotationMarkup();
    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
    PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(new COSStream());
    appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
    annot.setAppearance(appearance);

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdfDocument, appearanceStream);
    contentStream.addBezier(....);
    ..... more additions to the content stream
```

I've left the code to add the annotation to the page etc. of as this can be viewed from the `AddAnnotations.java`example in the examples package.

Comment: Please, add this command to the above code : appearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources()); , otherwise the setFont function of PDPageContentStream  will give exception.

Comment: Also, I am not able to add this markup to layer. I am able to add normal markups like PDAnnotationLink to any layer.But the same code does not work custom annotation.

Comment: Another thing the annotation is being created as unknown type PDFAnnotation . And it is not displayed when I open it in adobe reader or bluebeam. It is only visible in a third party pdf viewer library.It seems that adobe reader doesn't support unknown annotations type. So, how do I resolve this.